# C# Взять значение созданного класса

Tags: c#, классы

Вот есть код:

```
class ColorEl
{
    public ColorEl(int x, int y, ConsoleColor b, ConsoleColor f, string txt) {
        Console.BackgroundColor = b;
        Console.ForegroundColor = f;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(txt);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ColorEl el1 = new ColorEl(12, 3, ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black, "Drawing");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Можно ли взять например значение нового, созданного элемента el1 (x) и вывести отдельно?

```
Console.WriteLine(el1.GetValue(x));
```

Вот что-то вроде этого.

Comment: вывести - куда? Нет, нельзя, потому что это значение нигде не хранится.

Comment: Ну так создайте в классе `ColorEl` нужную `public` переменную, скажем `public int X;`. Ну а дальше в `public ColorEl(...)` добавьте заполнение этой переменной, скажем так: `X = x;`. Все, дальше просто пишите где нужно `el1.X;`

Comment: А зачем вам вообще понадобился класс? Всю свою работу он сделал в конструкторе, т.е. фактически он бесполезен, вам по сути нужна статическая функция. А параметры вы и так знаете, можете перед вызовом сохранить их переменные, и потом что-то с ними делать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ColorEl
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public ConsoleColor B { get; }
    public ConsoleColor F { get; }
    public string Txt { get; }

    /* или так
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public ConsoleColor B;
    public ConsoleColor F;
    public string Txt;
    */

    public ColorEl(int x, int y, ConsoleColor b, ConsoleColor f, string txt)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        B = b;
        F = f;
        Txt = txt;

        Console.BackgroundColor = b;
        Console.ForegroundColor = f;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(txt);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var e = new ColorEl(1, 0, ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Black, "");
    Console.WriteLine(e.X);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Ну-у-у, это нечестно. +1

Comment: Вызывать в конструкторе статические методы?

Comment: @Primus Singularis да криво/не красиво/не правильно, но это конкретный ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Vasek ну да, как в анекдоте про Холмса и воздушный шар.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ColorEl
{
    public static void WriteLine(int x, int y, ConsoleColor b, ConsoleColor f, string txt) 
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = b;
        Console.ForegroundColor = f;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(txt);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x=12; var y=3; 
    var bColor = ConsoleColor.White; 
    var fColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    ColorEl.WriteLine(x, y, bColor, fColor, "Drawing");
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```